# Autocomplete a dynamic field rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, nested-attributes

I am followed a railscasts about creating a nested attribute forms [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised).  So I have a piece of coffeescript that creates a user_mission object when the `add mission` button is pressed on my form.

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

A portion of the html generated looks like the following:

```
  <input id="user_user_missions_attributes_70324621482200_mission_title" name="user[user_missions_attributes][70324621482200][mission_title]" size="30" type="text" />
```

I am trying to add the ability to autocomplete functionality which looks into a list of already created missions to see if the user inputted mission already exists.  The problem is I am somewhat new to html and I am not sure how to add an autocomplete call to a dynamic html id.

Is there a clean way to locate the field that I need to add the autocomplete to?  Do I have to tokenize to search for `user_user_missions_attributes_70324621482200_mission_title`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try locating it by a partial-match of the name attribute. It won't be as fast but if you only have a few on each page, you won't notice a drop in page-loading performance.

```
$("input[name*='[mission_title]']")
```

You could also partial-match the ID but it doesn't seem as clean:

```
$("input[id*='_mission_title']")
```

You could also add a class to those fields and just use that.

Comment: I like the idea of using a class.  I looked up how to use it and I got it to work when the mission field is statically on the page but not when the jQuery above dynamically adds fields through the `add mission button`.

Comment: You'll need to make a new jQuery object once you've added a field, because jQuery objects are cached and won't pick up new DOM elements automatically.